# Delta type function

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, special-functions

I am looking for a function, $f(x)$ that is equal to 1 if $x=a$ and $0$ for any other value. Initially, I thought of delta function, but this equals $\infty$ at $x=a$. Any idea on what this could be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This is the [Indicator Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) for the set $\{a\} \in \Bbb{R}$.

Comment: A.k.a the *characteristic function* of the set $A=\{a\}$. Generally, for $A\subset X$, one has a function $\chi_A:X\to\{0,1\}$ with $\chi_A(x)=1$ if and only if $x\in A$. +1 for you.

Comment: Hello. Thanks. That is very helpful.